# in R data.table - mark/change column based on date by group

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to mark the maximum and minimum date of observations per ID using data.table. Whilst I thought that this would be a straight forward exercise, I do not really understand why I do not obtain the result I wish: for some reason the following data.table command only flags the overall min and max and not "per ID", even though this is indicated:

Reproducible example (to mark maximum value by ID):

```
library(data.table)

date1 = as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(), "%m-%d-%Y-%X")
date2 = date1 - 70000
date3 = date1 - 7000
date4 = date1 + 90000

DT = data.table(ID= rep(1:2,each = 3), Date=c(date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2))

# create position marker (2 means middle value for date - not min/not max)
DT[,Position:=2]

# change position marker to 3 if latest date
DT[Date==max(Date),Position:=3, by=ID]
```

Why does data.table not consider the "by=ID" part? What am I overlooking?

Version:
Data.table 1.9.2
R: 3.0.3

Comment: I think it filters the data first, and then does the ``by`` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is filtering the data, and the `by` statement follows.  Perhaps what you want is:

`DT[, Position := ifelse(Date==max(Date),3,2), by= ID]`

Comment: Indeed, the `i` argument is processed before the `by` argument

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. .. normally I get along quite well when working intuitively with i,j,by (the data.table package is one of the most useful tools in R)! Just failed this time... good to know the order of filtering now!